# Display Push Notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

I want create a app with push notification feature.

What i have done is register the app in google

And storing the resisted device id from app

And send notification from server.

All are work fine.

I send push to registered devices.

And I don't know how to display push notification when push comes.

Comment: Please read this tutorial and try things, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ There you can find a good explanation of Push Notifications

Comment: try this link: http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

Comment: try this link: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-multicast-push-notifications-using-gcm/

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `GcmListenerService`, below is an example:

```
/**
 * Service used for receiving GCM messages. When a message is received this service will log it.
 */
public class GcmService extends GcmListenerService {
  private final int PN_ID = 993;

  Booking mBooking;

  private static final String TYPE = "type";
  private static final String TITLE = "title";
  private static final String MESSAGE = "body";

  private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

  public GcmService() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(String from, final Bundle data) {

    String type = data.getString(TYPE, "");
    final String title = data.getString(TITLE, "");
    final String message = data.getString(MESSAGE, "");

    if (title.length() > 0 || message.length() > 0) {
      sendNotification(PN_ID, title, message);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDeletedMessages() {
    sendNotification(PN_ID, "Deleted messages on server", "");
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {
    sendNotification(PN_ID, "Upstream message sent. Id=" + msgId, "");
  }

  @Override
  public void onSendError(String msgId, String error) {
    sendNotification(PN_ID, "", "Upstream message send error. Id=" + msgId + ", error" + error);
  }

  // Post a notification indicating whether a doodle was found.
  private void sendNotification(int notificationId, String title, String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setAutoCancel(true);


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
  }


}
```

Register it in your manifest inside `<application>` like any other `Service`

```
    <service
        android:name=".services.GcmService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

You will need at least these permissions, I suspect you may even need `WAKE_LOCK`.

```
<!-- PUSH NOTIFICATIONS -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<permission
    android:name="au.com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="au.com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

In this setup, your payload that you send to the GCM service will look something like this:

```
{       
  "registration_ids":[],
  "data": {
    "title" : "Hello",
    "message" : "World",
  } 
}
```

Where `registration_ids` are the devices you want to send the message to, and the `data` is what will be delivered to you in the `Bundle`.

Comment: My compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion is 23

Above Code not working for me

Comment: That is what you have to do, what else you're missing I can't say.

Comment: Stupid question, have you specified the API key in the manifest? You have to generate an API key from the Google Developer Console andnincludebit in your project. Also, you have to implement code to get a push token for the device, you seem to claim that you have done this part, but it's not clear from your question.